# Linear combination of Slater Determinants

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, fermions, pauli-exclusion-principle, identical-particles

I've been reading about many particle states in quantum mechanics and came across the fact that combinations of fermions can be represented using a Slater determinant. This is quite easy to understand for purely spatial wavefunctions. However, there is big confusion, when we try to include spin.

Suppose I consider the excited state of Helium $1s2s$. There would be four combinations here. However, in two of those, where the two electrons have opposite spins, it is said that the wavefunction cannot be written as a product of spatial and spin parts. For example,

let $\alpha$ denote up spin and $\beta$ denote down spin. Suppose, I have the following combination ( $1s$-up, $2s$-down ) :

$$\psi_{1s}(1)\psi_{2s}(2)\alpha(1)\beta(2)-\psi_{1s}(2)\psi_{2s}(1)\alpha(2)\beta(1)$$

This is what I've got from the Slater Determinant. However, it is said that this cannot be written as $\psi_s\chi_s$, as in a product of spatial and spin parts. I see why that is true. But then I run into this problem :

What exactly does slater determinant represent ?

It clearly doesn't represent the wave function, in all cases at least. There are cases, like this, where slater determinants can not be separated into a spin part and a spatial part. In such cases, we take a linear combination of Slater determinants. However, what do the individual slater determinants represent? The combination that I denoted above? What does it represent?

Some sources claim, that Slater determinants represent the configuration of electrons. But that doesn't make sense to me. The configuration is the state, according to me. Then why do we have to take a linear superposition of these determinants?

Is the slater determinant, just another alternate formalism, as opposed to the spin-singlet/triplet wavefunctions ?

Comment: Why are you saying it doesn’t represent the wavefunction?  Note the product wavefunctions are for non-interacting systems, so linear combo of Slater determinants are there to keep full antisymmetry and allow for interactions to mix non-interacting states.

Comment: What if I define the system to be non-interacting, what about then ? I can say that the slater determinant is the linear sum of the singlet and triplet states, which makes it a possible wavefunction. However, which one is more fundamental ? Which one represents 1s2s ? Is it the spin singlet or triplet wavefunction, or is it the slater determinant. I've seen that linear combination of slater determinant gives us those wavefunctions. So, which one actually represents the 1s2s ?